# Force a parent's height with hidden child element in CSS

Tags: css, height, hidden

If I have a hidden child element (with either `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`), how can I have the parent `div` keeps it's height so that when the child is made visible, the parent height does not change?

Do I need to set an absolute height on the parent or can I still have it calculate its height from the child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display:none` removes the element from the flow, so no way to make the parent keept the height (other than hard-coding a fixed value). It should also hide it from screen readers and crawlers.

`visiblity:hidden` keeps the element in the flow, and therefore, keeps the space reserved for it, so the parent will keep the height just as if the element was visible.

`opacity:0` will also act just like `visibility:hidden`, while allowing the reveal of the element to be transitioned / animated to `opacity:1`.

So you should use either `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0`, depending on if you want to show the element in a jumpy reveal or transition.

### Edit:

It should also be noted that visibility:hidden will not fire events (such as a click, hover, etc) while opacity:0 will. So there are even some rare cases on which you could use both together. For instance, if you want the element to start hidden, then show up with a transition, and have another event linked to it that should fire only when the element is visible

In the following example, there's a click event linked to the div element that will fire only when visible (so couldn't use just the opacity), but also have a transition when revealing (so couldn't use just visibility)

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.opacity').toggleClass("visible");
});

$('.opacity').click(function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
    background: chartreuse;
}

.visibility{
  visibility:hidden;
}


.opacity{
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
}

.visible{
  opacity:1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
toggle
</button>

<div class="opacity"> opacity:0 </div>
<hr>
```

Comment: +1 Good point about the ability to transition the property or not. A drawback of `visibility` that is quite relevant in modern web applications.

Comment: @raphinesse thanks! I've also added a sidenote about events ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `visibility: hidden;` to hide the child, space will still be reserved for it. You can show it again, by setting `visibility: visible;`.

To cite the [MDN docs for `visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility):

> The `visibility` CSS property can show or hide an element without affecting the layout of a document (i.e., space is created for elements regardless of whether they are visible or not).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.